# Can windows scheduler jobs run under a non interactive service account?

Tags: windows

The OS is 2008 R2 64 bit, we have a few windows scheduler jobs, currently running under normal windows accounts, another team told us better minimize the rights and convert the windows accounts to non-interactive service account

Not much knowledge in these, questions:

1. What is the 'non interactive accounts'? any pro and cons?
2. Can the windows services and scheduler tasks configured to run under those accounts?

Appreciate the help! thanks in advance

Comment: non-interactive accounts cannot login to a desktop. Yes, non-interactive accounts can be used to run scheduled tasks, but the user must be configured to allow `login as batch job` or `login as service` in order to run their payload. you can set this properties in the local security policy or via GP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only privilege should have would be Log On as a Batch process.
To grant it go to -> Secpol.msc from cmd,  Security, local rights assesment.

1. non interactive are the ones cannot interact with desktop and running in session 0.
2. Yes.

Comment: thanks, that is the 'login as service' as pointed out by Frank above, does it required?

Comment: depends on whether the thing you are starting was registered as a service with the OS.

Comment: Depends on the purpose, if you wanna execute it as a service provide that privilege. What do you want to get run?